# recent Blender 2.77 start problems

Tags: 3d-view, windows, versions

Blender 2.77  opening with multiple anomalies. Windows wait cursor stuck on, loading previously closed/unsaved session, and closing/quitting without  displaying  Prompt/quit window even though it is enabled. Wait cursor goes away after clicking on viewport.

Tried  resetting factory settings and completely uninstalling and reloading. Still did not clear problems. Most recent actions prior to above, installing and uninstalling Booltool. (win os.7 64bt i5) any ideas? Thanks. jrt

Comment: Not so sure what you're on about, perhaps some screenshots if possible? Thanks!

Comment: Hum hard to tell, may be some graphical issue. Try downloading and running one of the "portable" zipped builds instead of a regular instaler setup and see if the problems persist. Unzip somewhere like the desktop or My Documents, and after unpacking be sure to create a folder called Config under "Blender/2.77/Config" so that it wont load any system profile configurations, and see if still has trouble.

Comment: Were you able to work in blender versions previous to this one? Has anything changed in your computer besides blender?